# Get first visible item in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to get position of first visible item in RecyclerView, because I need some information about it (e.g. title). Unfortunately when I'm using `LayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` it returns 0, all the time. 
Moreover, my RecyclerView is located in NestedScrollView. All this items are in PageAdapter (TabLayout). 
Here is my two method for setting up RecyclerView:

```
private void initializeAdapter() {
    NaBiezacoAktualnosciAdapter adapter = new NaBiezacoAktualnosciAdapter(items, getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void initializeLayoutManager(final View v) {
    final ExpansiveLayoutManager llm = new ExpansiveLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                }
            })
    );
    NestedScrollView nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.nested);
    nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            int firstVisibleCard = llm.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastVisibleCard = llm.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            Log.d("aaaa", "firstVisibleCard= " + firstVisibleCard);
            Log.d("aaaa", "lastVisibleCard= " + lastVisibleCard);
        }
    });
}
```

Do anybody have idea how to make this work? I'd be glad for any advice :)

Comment: But I don't need to set on item clicked listener. I want to achive something like this: I have layout anchored in the top, it display date of first visible item. When I scroll down date change to first visible item and so on. I just need to know position in adapter of first visible item.